# Replace pilcrows in strings

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, special-characters

I've spent far too much time trying to Google this and have not found one thing that is helping. I'm using PHP and I have data in a MySQL database text field that has strings that contain Pilcrows. I have tried exploding the data on **chr(182), \r\n, \n, \x0A\x0D, and %0A%0D**, but none of these are working.

This is the character causing me all this grief; ¶

I need the strings separated by these troublesome characters and am out of ideas or any Google results that are of any value thus far.

*Please don't flag this question as a duplicate as I have scoured SO here also looking for solutions. Seems there is one for MSSQL, but not MySQL and the two are too vastly different to translate the solutions across platforms.*

Comment: is it the literal character '¶' stored, or is it encoded?

Comment: I'm honestly not certain. When I view the data in Sequel Pro (On a Mac), I see nothing but the strings all on new lines as to imply that they are, in fact, the special chars instead of string literals. In the column view, I can see those P chars between the strings, but in the Text editor window, they are all just on new lines without the chars.

Comment: Can you please add `var_dump` output for one of the actual strings, and the field definition from the database? Also, how do you render / where do you see these characters?

Comment: You said "I have tried exploding the data on ..., but none of these are working" please show the actual code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploding by that character

```
$string = "This is the character¶ causing me all this grief; ¶I need the strings separated";
$array = explode("¶", $string);
```

Or if it is actually `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` or `"\r"` preg_split is the way to go. You can add whatever other possible characters to the regex inside the brackets.

```
$string = "This is the character\r\n causing me all this grief; \n need the strings separated";
$array = preg_split ("/[\r\n]/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

var_dump($array);
```

This should output the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "This is the character"
  [1]=>
  string(28) " causing me all this grief; "
  [2]=>
  string(28) "I need the strings separated"
```

}

Comment: This was a great suggestion and one I hadn't tried yet, but it doesn't appear to have helped, sadly.

Comment: Okay...just weird! I just viewed the string copied from the DB in a site that lets you view non-visible chars and it displayed them as CR & LF. So, why on earth is '/\r\n/' not working then?

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Never have I had such a royal pain in the a** with character parsing issues! Alas, I have found a solution that at least allowed me to explode the characters. GRRR!!!

This is ultimately what worked and I hope it helps someone from going through the crap I just had to endure!

```
$encoded = urlencode($soRow['employees_on_site']);
$EOS_parts = explode('%0D%0A', $encoded);
print "<pre>"; print_r($EOS_parts); print "</pre>";
```

This was seriously a major waste of precious dev time!